# Reading the month part in the date in c++

Tags: c++, function, datetime, date, datetime-format

I have two dates namely the filecreation date and the system date both in the int format as

```
        "20120304","20120404" which is something like YYYYMMDD.
```

i just want to take the MM part of these two dates these two dates are returned from a function as integers .

Please suggest some examples

Thanks

Comment: in actual yyyy is y,mm is m and dd is d,and they had been concatenated to a variable date as date=y + m +d;

Comment: Your statement that the representation is an integer does not make sense with your statement that the year, month and date values were simply concatenated using + to produce the final value.  Are you certain that your date is not represented as an 8 character string?

Comment: Modify your question to show what type you are talking about: is it a string or an integer. Also say what you have tried. Also read [How To Ask Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

although i prefer @keety's answer,there is an other way.
u can use string streams:

for eg:

```
#include <sstream>

int i = 5;
std::string s;
std::stringstream out;
out << i;
s = out.str();
```

so after you have your string as `YYYYMMDD` in a string varaible.
`substr(4,2)` will be your month.
you can later on use `strtol` for converting back to integer.

Comment: :i got something and got confused with the other suppose i have y,d,m as three string streams and all these are concatenated to another string as"date=y+m+d;"and then this is converted to integer as return atoi(date.c_str());

so how do i take the substr now from it when it is already an integer

Comment: and the code would look something like int mm = date.substr(4,2);where date is returned as an integer.

Answer (score 3):

since it is  `int` type use `int mm=(yyyymmdd/100)%100`

Comment: @keely:what is it doing "int mm =(yyyymmdd/100)%100"

Comment: @gandhigcpp  `yyyymmdd/100` would extract yyyymm and following it up  by mod operator  `yyyymm%100` would extract the mm part

Comment: @keealy:as i discussed it is something like this
        
        date = y + m + d;//was a string here
        return atoi(date.c_str());//returns integer to the function

Comment: :one thing i forgot to mention that y,m,d are the string streams...please sugget according to it

Comment: i think worked the best for me :-

     int mm = atoi(date.substr(4,2).c_str());//month for system date
     int mm1 = atoi(date1.substr(4,2).c_str());//month for filecreation date

thanks all for u r support
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If they are always in the format `YYYYMMDD`, then take the substring at [4] for length 2.

Comment: they are in the format of YYYYMMDD however this is an integer and not a string

Comment: @gandhigcpp:  Then ignore my answer and use keety's.  I'll delete mine in a few hours.

Comment: :that is something not good i dont want u to do that it is also a good answer but code makes it more easy to understand for a novice like me